# What can this microchip be?

Tags: identification

I found this device in my bag one day. It is a small device powered by a CR1632 3V lithium battery, but I have no idea what it is.

After disassembling it I see a chip. I can read the number in the bottom right corner - it looks like it reads `RC-ZN7_LC_WB_V1.0`

It looks like it might be a GPS tracker or something like that. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a bluetooth tracker..?

Comment: It looks more like it is (or was anyway) a remote control for something, like a garage door. What would it be tracking and why anyway?

Comment: My guess would be a remote control of some sort. Can you provide a photo of the other side of the PCB? What does the text on the IC say?

Comment: The yellow thing in the middle looks like a touch-sensor to me. So I doubt it's a tracker. Rather some kind of remote control, like winny suggested.

Comment: Could it be a Bluetooth selfie remote shutter button? [This video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/k0RhPNagudQ) has a picture of a similar chip, button, battery.  Although those, and garage door openers, tend to have a keyring attachment.

Comment: Google "433mhz rf round push button" and you'll find a lot of similar looking devices. Pretty sure it's a remote control for something.

Comment: There has been a lot of really good guesses, but I really think that @Klas-Kenny is on to something here. If you want to make an answer, I would like to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is a remote control for *something*.

Search for `433MHz RF round push button` using your favorite search engine, and you'll find lots of very similar looking devices.

Answer (score 1):

It has a small battery and an antenna. I'm gonna go with being a Bluetooth device. There are a couple of thing that looks like this:

- Bluetooth trackers like Tile or AirTag. If there are no sensors, buzzer or any visible LED and it just sits there, it's more likely to be a tracker. They send out a beacon that can be detected by a Bluetooth receiver. It is a cheap way to track lost or stolen property. For example, you put it in your bag, and if you lose it, the phones around the device (that support that device) will pick up the signal and report it to a server. Later on, you can see the last location of the phone that could scan the beacon. This way, you will have an estimated location of the device.
- Bluetooth finder. If it has a buzzer on it, it's more likely that this is a Bluetooth finder. You pair it with your phone, and then if you lose your device (like your keychain), you can use an app on your phone to start the buzzer.
- Simple transmitter. The button could be a simple command for a receiver. In that case, it could be any other frequency than the Bluetooth. However, it could be for pairing the Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The marking on the device are barely visible, but you can see the antenna trace (lower right side of the PCB). It is most likely a transceiver of some sort.